# Different ways to apply plugins ? (Gradle Kotlin DSL)

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to migrate a project's Gradle files to the Gradle Kotlin DSL.

We have this in Groovy:

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    ...
    sourceSets {
        ...
    }
    sourceCompatibility = ...
}
```

While figuring out how to access the plugin convention in Kotlin, I found:

```
allprojects {
    plugins {
        java apply true
    }
    ...
    println("Project $name, plugins: ${plugins}") // empty list
    val java = the<JavaPluginConvention>() // throws exception
}
```

However, if I do it like this:

```
allprojects {
    apply {
        plugin(JavaPlugin::class.java)
    }
}
```

The plugin is applied and convention becomes accessible.

WTH?

Comment: did you try `configurations.provided` ?

Comment: My problem is that the value returned by my extension java getter is null

Answer (score 15):

This issue isn't specific to Kotlin, and is due to a race condition.  While the script is being evaluated, it may not have added the plugin to the classpath yet.  This is one of many reasons why the `plugins` block was created, as it's specifically evaluated prior to the rest of the scripts evaluation during a `buildscript` phase.  That said however, this special treatment is only done if this block is at the top of the script, and not when it's within a `subprojects` or `allprojects` block, as those blocks are technically arbitrary and are evaluated later to ensure the `buildscript` is idempotent.  In your case, you are just moving up the race by placing it in `allprojects` block, and are getting lucky.

When dealing with multi-project builds, this is problematic, however if possible, the best is to declare the plugin in the `plugins` block with the `apply false` constrained syntax to add it to your build's classpath in the `buildscript` phase.  You will then be able to apply the plugin later via the plugin's id during script evaluation (version isn't necessary, as it's used for fetching the dependency only).

An example:

```
plugins {
    id("org.gradle.sample.hello") version "1.0.0" apply false
}

subprojects {
    apply(plugin = "org.gradle.sample.hello")
}
```

The [Gradle User Guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html) does a great job at explaining how these should be used, and the balance you will need to consider in multi-module projects.

Due to the nature of how some plugins are written, there may be cases where other issues will arise, but if plugin authors are following best practice guidelines, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If your plugins are for Kotlin, then the best way for now is:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.21"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.7.21"
}
```